# VB6 ADO Transactions

Tags: sql-server, transactions, vb6, ado

I am working with an old VB6 application. Unfortunately it uses multiple connections to the same database.

I am trying to implement a series of updates to the database that need to use 3 of the 4 connections to perform the functionality. This is a much simplified example of my code:

```
Sub UpdateTables()
  conn1.BeginTrans
  conn2.BeginTrans
  conn3.BeginTrans

  'locate the 1st recordset on conn1
  'modify the 1st recordset
  rs1.Update
  ' any errors go to Failure

  'locate the 2nd recordset on conn2
  'modify the 2nd recordset
  rs2.Update                 '<--------------------
 ' any errors go to Failure

  'locate the 3rd recordset on conn3
  'modify the 3rd recordset
  rs3.Update
  ' any errors go to Failure

  ' success
  conn3.CommitTrans
  conn2.CommitTrans
  conn1.CommitTrans
ExitSub:
  rs1.Close
  rs2.Close
  rs3.close
  Exit Sub

 Failure:
  conn3.RollbackTrans
  conn2.RollbackTrans
  conn1.RollbackTrans
  Goto ExitSub
End Sub
```

With this logic, the process hangs at the second update, I have to kill the process.

With what I've read up about this, this should be possible

Comment: Each connection is independent here so a connection will be blocked if it tries to access data locked by another request.  It may be you just need index/query tuning so that only the data that needs to be updated is touched to avoid that.  Alternatively, you could also use a single connection with MARS enabled so the same transaction context is used.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130978.aspx.

Comment: hmmm.... I'll look into MARS. The "recordsets" being updates are procedures, to there may well be common tables. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: You'll lose a lot less hair in the future if you rewrite now to use only one connection. I'm pretty sure MARS isn't the droid you're looking for.